# Parallel.ForEach and Dictionary collection results in null key

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I don't understand how my code went wrong here's a code piece:

```
var filter = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,bool>>();
//data here is of type Dictionary<string,bool>
Parallel.ForEach(data, t =>
{
    var filter1 = data.Where(p => p.Value).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
    filter.Add(t.key, filter1);
});
```

Sometimes, the final `filter` has a `null` key in it, which has never happened if I had used a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [this] has never happened if I had used a simple for loop.

The problem is that you are adding to `filter` concurrently. You could fix this by using `AsParallel()`:

```
var filter = data.AsParallel().ToDictionary(t =>
    t.Key
,   data.Where(p=>p.Value).ToDictionary(p=>p.Key, p=>p.Value)
);
```

Comment: thank you, that works but can you tell me the reason why the method behaved like that, even if I was adding data concurrently, there was no null key in the data, so how can the parallel class creates some fictitious task that shouldn't have existed

Comment: @JokingBear When a dictionary gets modified concurrently, its internal data structure becomes invalid, especially when buckets get rebalanced. Concurrent updates write over the data of each other, so keys and/or values appear `null`, even though non-`null` items have been supplied to the `Add` method. In fact, you cannot legally pass a `null` key to the dictionary without triggering an exception.

Comment: @JokingBear: "so how can the parallel class creates some fictitious task that shouldn't have existed" - because you're using `Dictionary<,>` in a way that's unsupported. It's simply not suitable for multi-threaded modification. From the docs: "To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization." Once you're outside the supported scenarios, the way that problems manifest isn't specified.